# How to display data using two records for one title name multiple press names by using comma in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image]
In first table i had press event titles

[image]
In Second table i had press event title id and press names

[image]

By using above two tables i want to display press titles and pressnames by using comma seperated.
example:  Polio drops(title) -- Hyderabad,Chennai,Banglore  etc...(names)

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand. Please replace the images with text. Use `show create table myTableName` mysql query to output and display the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `join` this two tables and then use `group_concat` like this:

```
Select t1.title, group_concat (t2.press_name)
From table1 t1
Left join table2 t2 on t2.press_title=t1.id
Group by 1
```